# How to disable [WARN] messages to log to console while RobotFramework is running from jenkins

Tags: jenkins, robotframework

When I start my job on jenkins, there is output:

```
[ WARN ] TSV file '/home/robot/NightlyRegression/robot_frame/SP100-newSetup-10.2/54xx_Resources/OSA_User_Keywords.tsv' has quotes around cells which is deprecated and must be fixed. Remove quotes from '"""${media.upper()}""==""FIBER"""' on line 329.
[ WARN ] TSV file '/home/robot/NightlyRegression/robot_frame/SP100-newSetup-10.2/54xx_Resources/OSA_User_Keywords.tsv' has quotes around cells which is deprecated and must be fixed. Remove quotes from '"""${media.upper()}""==""COPPER"""' on line 330.
[ WARN ] TSV file '/home/robot/NightlyRegression/robot_frame/SP100-newSetup-10.2/54xx_Resources/OSA_User_Keywords.tsv' has quotes around cells which is deprecated and must be fixed. Remove quotes from '"""${media.upper()}""==""FIBER"""' on line 338.
[ WARN ] TSV file '/home/robot/NightlyRegression/robot_frame/SP100-newSetup-10.2/54xx_Resources/OSA_User_Keywords.tsv' has quotes around cells which is deprecated and must be fixed. Remove quotes from '"""${media.upper()}""==""COPPER"""' on line 339.
[ WARN ] TSV file '/home/robot/NightlyRegression/robot_frame/SP100-newSetup-10.2/54xx_Resources/OSA_User_Keywords.tsv' has quotes around cells which is deprecated and must be fixed. Remove quotes from '"""${media.upper()}""==""FIBER"""' on line 382.
```

Do you know how can I disable this [Warn] message?

thanks

Comment: Do as the msg says and remove the quotes ...?

Comment: there is 1000+ warnings.
its working, that the reason its just warning.

Comment: " .. has quotes around cells [which is deprecated](https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/issues/2819) and must be fixed". If you figure out how to hide the warning, you'll have a hard fail when they [remove](https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/issues/3081) the feature and it stops working. Good luck.  You also appear to be some versions behind.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.
after some invetigation, I found that happened because of the version of the robot-framework.
I upgraded the version to the newest, and that why this warns appeared.

when I restored the version to 3.0.4 - this warns had dissapeared.